# Trying to style openlayers3

Tags: javascript, html, css, openlayers-3

How am I supposed to style openlayers3 in the best way possible? I'm really struggling with this. The easiest way for me is to change the original ol.css, but that is not good practice.

For example, changing the placement of the control buttons to the right took me quite a while.

Should I do this with CSS or in JavaSCript?

I'm currently having issues with removing the tool-tip when hovering the buttons. How do I do that?

The tooltip has the class:

```
.ol-has-tooltip [role=tooltip]
```

How do I hide it?

```
display:hidden
```

does not work.

Thanks for any advice and help.

Comment: Can't you import http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/css/ol.css normally and then override the ones you wish to change in inline css, or another imported css after that import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will do

```
display:none;
```

try to use !important to overide already existed css property